# compare a two tables and mention the newly changed values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is the simple example in which am struggling with,

What I Need is to compare the two table (Table: Old and Table:New) and get a new table by mentioning the changed items either in column 'ProductID' or 'Quantity' in the Result table.

Example Table

[image]

To say clearly,
--If we check for 'John' He has a product '3BV' Newly, So it should be mentioned as 'changed'.
--If we check for 'Sara' she left a product '1TV' , So not need to mention in Result Table.
--If we check for 'pete' Its a completely newly added person.
--If we check for 'Paul' the Quantity of Product ID :1OV alone changed so need to mention in Result Table.

Is there any way to make formula to check the changes (Column 'L') as mentioned in result Table?

I have a big data of around 4000 rows like this
Can anyone please help me in This ?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS`. If 0 result in old table > "Changed". If 1 result in old table > "NoChanges"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

[image]

Formula in `L3`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$13,I3,$B$3:$B$13,J3,$C$3:$C$13,K3),"NoChange","Changed")
```

Comment: Super...Thanks a lot @JvdV